# How to install test version of Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I published an update to my chrome extension (without submitting for review) and the extension's status is now "Published to testers" but I can't figure out how to install the test version.

I added my email address as a trusted tester account but when I open the extension's page in the chrome web store it still lists the old version.

What am I doing wrong?